# In React, how do you properly programmatically navigate to a new route/page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been trying to find a straight answer to this and even after searching StackOverflow, I can't find a correct answer for the current version of React.

In my case, I have the following scenario-- the user sets up their data, they post it to the server and within my `Save()` method, if the save operation is successful, I want to redirect them to the root home page.

Much of the documentation I've found mentions using `this.props.history.push(...)` to push the new route. However, something has changed with React 4.0.0+ and now `history` is undefined on the props page.

I am not necessarily interested in pushing the new route to the history object if that is a deprecated way of routing to another page.  However, all of the more current examples I've found talk about setting up routes and links within the JSX.  That's fine, but I've yet to find a way to programmatically redirect the page un certain code conditions.

Apologies if there is an answer out this already, but I haven't found a straight answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) are only given to the components that are used for the `component` or `render` props of the `Route` components.

If you want to use the route props in any other component in your app, you need to pass the props manually or use the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect this component with router. To connect you have to use withRouter.

```
export default withStyles(commonModalStyle)(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewOrUpdateModal)));
```

Please refer this